# How to send email with LINQ result in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-c#-express-2010

Good day

I've a controller with which i consult records by means of an ID, when consulting, it shows me the records
stored with that ID but how can I send those results by email by clicking on a submit button?

This's my controller

```
    public ActionResult Search(decimal? reqid, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        var req = from s in db.TB_CS_TEST
                  join st in db.TB_CS_TEST2 on s.REQ_NO equals st.REQ_NO
                  where s.REQ_NO.Equals(st.REQ_NO)
                  select new SearchModels
                  {
                      GetTB1 = s,
                      GetTB2 = st
                  };
        if (reqid.HasValue)
        {
            req = req.Where(s => s.GetTB1.REQ_NO == reqid);
        }
        return View(req);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I'm aware that an SMPT client is used but my question is how to send the results that the view throws in the body of the email.

This's my email function

```
        public void SendEmail()
    {
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("send@email.com", ""); //This is an example user
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Host = "154.127.1.150"; // This is an example Host
        mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("user@email.com", "email");
        mail.To.Add("user2@email.com");
        mail.Subject = "SUB";
        mail.Body = ""; // HERE IS THE BODY THAT I WANT TO FILL WITH VIEW RESULT
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
```

This's my view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication31.Models.SearchModels>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search</h2>
  @using (Html.BeginForm()){    
      <p> Request Number: @Html.TextBox("reqid") <br />   
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
      } 
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Req No</td>
        <td>Item Number</td>
        <td>Item Name</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Event Date</td>
        <td>Event Place</td>
        <td>Purpose</td>
        <td>Approver 1</td>
        <td>Approver 2</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.REQ_NO</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.SEQ_NO</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.ITEM_NAME</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.QUANTITY</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB1.UOM</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.EVENT_DATE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.EVENT_PLACE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.PURPOSE</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.APPROVER1</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.APPROVER2</td>
            <td>@item.GetTB2.STATUS</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

As you can see my goal is to be able to send the values ​​of @ item.GetTB1 and @ item.GetTB2 in the body of the email

Thank you

Comment: Please describe what you have tried, where you are stuck, etc. An SMTP client is a typical way of sending an email, but you will have to do your own research. As is the question is much too open and will likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment John Sloper , i put more information about my question in EDIT:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only i need a StringWriter and then use as email body

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }

        //public void SendEmail(IQueryable<TB_RS_PROD> s)
        public ActionResult SendEmail(string s,string ss)
        {
            decimal sl = (decimal)TempData["rt"];
            string acceptable = "a|tr|td|table|html|img|br|th|thead|tbody"; //Tags OK
            string stringPattern = @"</?(?(?=" + acceptable + @")notag|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+=?(?:(["",']?).*?\1?)?)*\s*/?>";
            var htmlp = RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/ActionApprovers/Action.cshtml", TempData["email-act"]);
            htmlp = Regex.Replace(htmlp, stringPattern, "");
            var link = "<a href='http://localhost:62357/"
                + @Url.Action("Action", "ActionApprovers", new { idprod = sl })
                + "'>Click here to review request</a>";
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("send@email.com", "");
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Host = "154.127.1.150";
            mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("send@email.com", "admin");
            mail.To.Add(s);
            //mail.To.Add(ss); 
            mail.Subject = "Request ";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body += "<style>";
            mail.Body += "*, *:before, *:after { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; } body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; } table { background: #ffffff; border: 0.25px solid black; border-radius: 0.25em; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em; } th { border-bottom: 1px solid #364043; color: #ffffff; background-color: #a50034; font-size: 0.85em; font-weight: 600; padding: 0.5em 1em; text-align: left; } td { color: #000; font-weight: 400; padding: 0.65em 1em; } .disabled td { color: #000; } tbody tr { transition: background 0.25s ease; } tbody tr:hover { background: #000 }  tr:hover td { color: #fff;} p { color: #000000; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; } p.thick { color: #000000; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; }";
            mail.Body += "</style>";
            mail.Body += "<p> CAFETERIA SERVICE REQUEST: " + "<b>#" + sl + "</b></p>";
            mail.Body += "<br/>";
            mail.Body += "<br/>";
            mail.Body += htmlp;
            mail.Body += "<br/>";
            mail.Body += "<br/>";
            mail.Body += "<p>You have received a cafeteria special service approval, Please access below link to review it <p>";
            mail.Body += link;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return View("~/Views/Home/About.cshtml");
        }
```